# How to enable response time logging in Jetty 7

Tags: jetty, logback

Apache and Tomcat both make it easy to log response times out to the server access log (with the %D pattern), but I've been unable to find any equivalent support in Jetty, either with the default `NCSARequestLog` or using logback-access (my preferred logging setup).

Is there a way of getting Jetty to log these times?  I could see it being possible to use a custom handler of some kind to gather this information and make it available to the logging handler, but am hopeful that something like the `StatisticsHandler` could do it for me as it's clearly already tracking this information to generate its aggregate stats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `setLogLatency(true)` on `NCSARequestLog`

Comment: Excellent, no idea how I missed that one.  Is there an equivalent approach to logging response times using logback-access?  `NCSARequestLog` doesn't offer the breadth of log format and appender mechanisms I need for some of our more advanced use cases.

Answer (score 2):

A good detailed explanation on how to enable response time logging through configuration is here: [Monitoring latency in Jetty request log](http://dsharpdotnet.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/monitoring-latency-in-jettys-request-log/)

Summary:

> Open [JETTY HOME]/etc/jetty.xml.
>
> Locate <Ref id=”RequestLog”> section.
>
> Add Set name=”logLatency”>true to setter list.
>
> Save it and restart Jetty.

Answer (score 0):

Using logback access 1.1.0 or later, you can use the `%elapsedTime` conversion word to get the response time in ms. From https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html :

> ```
> D / elapsedTime      The time taken to serve the request, in milliseconds.
> T / elapsedSeconds   The time taken to serve the request, in seconds.
> ```

For example, using:

```
<pattern>%h %l %u [%t] "%r" %s %b "%i{Referer}" "%i{User-Agent}" %elapsedTime{}ms</pattern>
```

Will output:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [03/Jun/2018:08:07:12 +1200] "GET /actuator/health HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36" 3ms
```